# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'content/movies_fights/'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I've downloaded dataset from kaggle and when running that in colab it shows the following error.

here is the code>>>

```
import os

k = 1
cross_validation = 5

datasets_path = ['content/movies_fights/', 'content/hockey_fights/', 'content/violent_flows/']
data_set = datasets_path[0]

split_f1_Train, split_f1_Test, split_f2_Train, split_f2_Test = list(), list(), list(), list()
f1x, f2x = list(), list()

for file in os.listdir(data_set):
    if file.split(' ')[0] == 'NV':
        f1x.append(file)
    else:
        f2x.append(file)
```

Comment: It might be 'drive/content/movies_fights/' 
Where is your dataset located? (If you right-click on the item you are trying to find and click (Copy Path) it will allow you to confirm the path is correct.

Comment: @Xammax  'drive/content/movies_fights/' isn't working. where I will right click to copy path? I haven't found anything like that after right-clicks to cells and loc.

Comment: Are you logged into your account on Colab? Sorry, I suggested backwards.

Use this code to have it be /content/drive/your_google_drive_etc/path_to_file/

Once you've logged in, you will want to look on the left middle part on your screen. (probably 75-80% from the bottom) click the folder icon. This will be two spots under the magnifying class. (Not including 0.) From there, you can examine your path with the right-click method.

Comment: @Xammax thank you. The issue has been solved. The path needed to be defined.

Comment: Glad to help. Best of luck sir.